# Highlight more than one anchor

Tags: html, css

I would like to highlight two sections of a page at the same time.

Currently I have the following:

```
<li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance##French">| French Creole</a></li>
```

and I would like this footer link to anchor and highlight the following sections:

```
<p id="French"><strong>French Creole</strong><br />
    ATANSYON: Si w pale Krey&ograve;l Ayisyen, gen s&egrave;vis &egrave;d pou lang ki disponib gratis pou ou. Rele 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p id="French"><strong>French</strong><br />
    ATTENTION: Si vous parlez fran&ccedil;ais, des services d'aide linguistique vous sont propos&eacute;s gratuitement. Appelez le 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>
```

This is the CSS I am using to highlight the selected section:

```
    #French:target{
     background-color: #ffa;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Currently, it will anchor and highlight the French Creole. How can I  highlight both sections?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @j08691: yes I understand but how would I highlight both section with the footer link I have and I have updated with the highlight part

Comment: If the sections to be highlit are sequential, I'd wrap them both into a single element with that ID.   If you need to highlight separate, non-sequential portions of the page, I believe you're going to have to resort to javascript; there isn't a CSS-only way to do that based on a link `:target`.

Comment: @DanielBeck: What would be the Javascript approach to it and it is non-sequential portions of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript way**

```
<li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a onclick="mulselect()">| French Creole</a></li>
```

Calling a javascript function using onclick listener, getting all elements with French class as array and then iterating over them to change the style.

```
function mulselect(){
    french=document.getElementsByClassName("French");
    for( i in french ) {
  french[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

**CSS way** "If they are at one place"

Note the change in href attribute, Now link targets to parent div of the elements to be selected.

```
<li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="#targetarea">| French Creole</a></li>
```

Wrap these p tags in a parent div with target id

```
<div id="targetarea">
<p class="French"><strong>French Creole</strong><br />
ATANSYON: Si w pale Krey&ograve;l Ayisyen, gen s&egrave;vis &egrave;d pou lang ki disponib gratis pou ou. Rele 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>
<p class="French"><strong>French</strong><br />
ATTENTION: Si vous parlez fran&ccedil;ais, des services d'aidelinguistique vous sont propos&eacute;s gratuitement. Appelez le 1-321-68-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>
<p class="English"><strong>French</strong><br />
ATTENTION: Si vous parlez fran&ccedil;ais, des services d'aidelinguistique vous sont propos&eacute;s gratuitement. Appelez le 1-321-68-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>
</div>
```

Now change the CSS to this

```
#targetarea:target .French{
 background-color: #ffa;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
```

Now you have more control over selection i.e. Only elements with class French will be highlighted
`